# Not sorting of struct using arrays

Tags: c++, qsort

It seems to be a simply exercise, but something doesn't work with the following qsort algorithmus. The `struct abcSort` correctly shows all assigned values. Unfortunately, the `qsort` is not sorting anything.

```
typedef int(*compfn)(const void*, const void*);

struct ABCSort
{
    int svSort[10];
    string itemSort[10];
};

struct ABCSort abcSort;

int compare(struct ABCSort*, struct ABCSort*);

void mainSort()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        abcSort.svSort[i] = 100 - i;
        abcSort.itemSort[i] = arrayREAD[i][2];
    }

    qsort( (void*)&abcSort, 10, sizeof(struct ABCSort), (compfn)compare );
}

int compare(struct ABCSort *elem1, struct ABCSort *elem2)
{
    if (elem1->svSort< elem2->svSort)
        return -1;
    else if (elem1->svSort > elem2->svSort)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using this in C++?! Switch to using the standard library and apply `std::sort` with a custom criterion.

Comment: Please read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort. The first argument of `qsort` is the array to sort, you're passing a struct instead. What you want to do is to switch from a struct of arrays to an array of structs, and sort those.

Comment: @iksemyonov though for some classes, `qsort` might be too 'raw' and invoke undefined behaviour by doing things it shouldn't. this is c++; using the stl is usually the best recommendation.

Comment: Also: Welcome to stackoverflow. The preferred way of saying thanks here is by upvoting or and/ or accepting answers to your questions. You might consider accepting some of the answers to your previous questions, which also gives you some reputation points.

Comment: The only C++ I can see is in the tag...... (apart form that, I agree to your comments regarding usage of standard library)

Comment: Is there any chance that your actual task is to sort an array (or better a vector) of 10 structs each one containing an int and a string, ordering the result by the int?

Comment: Bob, correct I simply wanted to sort the struct (int, string)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have build two arrays of integer and strings and you want to sort them by the numbers, keeping the initial pairing. That's the first problem, you should have created *one* array of structs, each struct containg a number and a string and a function that compares the integer member of that struct to obtain the sort order.

You also tagged this question as C++ but you are using `qsort`, arrays and function pointers like C, so I'll present two complete C programs that solve your problem.

---

Let's see, using an **array of structs**, what your code could be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 6
#define CMAX 15

typedef int(*cmp_fn)(const void*, const void*);

typedef struct {
    int num;
    char str[CMAX];
} numABC;

int comp_struct(const numABC *lhs, const numABC *rhs ) { 
    if ( lhs->num < rhs->num ) 
        return -1; 
    if ( lhs->num > rhs->num ) 
        return 1; 
    return 0;
} 

int main(void) {

    numABC myArray[MAX] = { {6, "cat"}, {4, "dog"}, {8, "panter"},
                         {2, "red fish"}, {1, "hawk"}, {6, "snake"} };
    int i;

    // sort the array of structs by int member
    qsort(myArray, MAX, sizeof(numABC), (cmp_fn)comp_struct);

    // print out the sorted array
    printf("\nSort by numbers:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        printf("%d %s\n",myArray[i].num,myArray[i].str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to use this code, but you have a couple of arrays instead, one option is to convert those arrays:

```
int nums[MAX] = {6,4,8,2,1,3};
char str[MAX][CMAX] = {"cat","dog","panter","red fish","hawk","snake"};
int i;

// create the array of structs from the two arrays
numABC myArray[MAX];
for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
    myArray[i].num = nums[i];
    strcpy(myArray[i].str, str[i]);
}
```

---

Another option to sort **two different arrays** (mantaining the pairing or alignment between the two) is to use a more complicated method which consists in sorting an array of indeces instead. to keep the relationships between the two original arrays I'll have to use global variables which can be accessed inside the compare function(s). Once the indeces are sorted, the original arrays are changed accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 6
#define CMAX 15

const size_t I_DIM = MAX * sizeof(int);
const size_t SS_DIM = MAX * sizeof(char*);
const size_t S_DIM = MAX * CMAX;

// global variables needed to perform comparisons   
int *pg_int;
char **pg_str;

typedef int(*cmp_fn)(const void*, const void*);

int comp_num(const int *lhs, const int *rhs ) { 
    if (pg_int[*lhs] < pg_int[*rhs]) 
        return -1; 
    if (pg_int[*lhs] > pg_int[*rhs]) 
        return 1; 
    return 0;
} 

int comp_str(const int *lhs, const int *rhs ) { 
    return strcmp(pg_str[*lhs],pg_str[*rhs]);
} 

int main(void) {
    int nums[MAX] = {6,4,8,2,1,3};
    char str[MAX][CMAX] = {"cat","dog","panter","red fish","hawk","snake"};
    int i;

    // create an array of indeces 
    int index[MAX];
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        index[i] = i;
    }

    // set global copies
    pg_int = malloc(I_DIM);
    memcpy(pg_int,nums,I_DIM);
    pg_str = malloc(SS_DIM);
    pg_str[0] = malloc(S_DIM);
    memcpy(pg_str[0],str[0],S_DIM);
    for ( i = 1; i < MAX; i++ ) {
        pg_str[i] = pg_str[0] + i * CMAX;
    }

    // sort the indeces ordering by ints
    qsort(index, MAX, sizeof(int), (cmp_fn)comp_num);

    //update the two arrays
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        nums[i] = pg_int[index[i]];
        strcpy(str[i],pg_str[index[i]]);
    }

    // print out sorted couples
    printf("Sort by numbers:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        printf("%d %s\n",nums[i],str[i]);
    }

    // sort the indeces ordering by strings
    qsort(index, MAX, sizeof(int), (cmp_fn)comp_str);

    //update the two arrays
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        nums[i] = pg_int[index[i]];
        strcpy(str[i],pg_str[index[i]]);
    }

    // print out sorted couples
    printf("\nSort by strings:\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; ++i ) {
        printf("%d %s\n",nums[i],str[i]);
    }

    free(pg_int);
    free(pg_str[0]);
    free(pg_str);
    return 0;
}
```

The output (sorry for the silly example) is:

```
Sort by numbers:
1 hawk
2 red fish
3 snake
4 dog
6 cat
8 panter

Sort by strings:
6 cat
4 dog
1 hawk
8 panter
2 red fish
3 snake
```

---

If you want to accomplish the same task in C++ you should take advantage of the Standard Library and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) as a container and [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

struct numABC {
    double num;
    string str;

    // instead of a compare function I can overload operator <
    friend bool operator<( const numABC &lhs, const numABC &rhs ) {
        return lhs.num < rhs.num;
    }
};

// or use a lambda
auto cmp_str = []( const numABC &lhs, const numABC &rhs ) -> bool {
    return lhs.str < rhs.str;
};

int main() {

    vector<numABC> my_data = { {3.6, "cat"}, {5.7, "dog"}, {7.1, "panter"},
                         {0.2, "red fish"}, {1.8, "hawk"}, {1.1, "snake"}};

    std::sort(my_data.begin(), my_data.end());

    std::cout << "Sort by numbers:\n";
    for ( auto & s : my_data ) {
        std::cout << s.num << ' ' << s.str << '\n';
    }

    std::sort(my_data.begin(), my_data.end(), cmp_str);
    // passing a lambda to specify how to compare ^^

    std::cout << "Sort by strings:\n";
    // if you don't like c++11 range for:
    for ( int i = 0; i < my_data.size(); ++i ) {
        std::cout << my_data[i].num << ' ' << my_data[i].str << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I have initialized `my_data` as a **vector of objects** of type numABC. If you have to start from two arrays, you can create the vector like this:

```
vector<double> nums = {3.6, 5.7, 7.1, 0.2, 1.8, 1.1};
vector<string> str = {"cat", "dog", "panter", "red fish", "hawk", "snake"};
vector<numABC> my_data;

for ( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i ) {
    my_data.push_back(numABC{nums[i],str[i]});
}
```

After sorting, if you have to extract the two vectors again (instead of simply looping through my_data) you can do something like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < my_data.size(); ++i ) {
    nums[i] = my_data[i].num;
    str[i] = my_data[i].str;
}
```

---

Alternatively you could implement an algorithm similar to the one I used before and **sort the two vectors** `nums` and `srt` *using an auxiliary vector of indeces*:

```
vector<double> nums = {3.6, 5.7, 7.1, 0.2, 1.8, 1.1};
vector<string> str = {"cat", "dog", "panter", "red fish", "hawk", "snake"};

// create the vector of indeces
vector<int> idx(nums.size());
std::iota(idx.begin(),idx.end(),0); // fill the vector, require #include <numeric>

// thanks to the lambda variable capture you don't need globals
auto cmp_ind = [ &nums ]
           ( const int &lhs, const int &rhs ) -> bool {
    return nums[lhs] < nums[rhs];
};

// sort indeces 
std::sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),cmp_ind);

// create sorted arrays. It could be done in place but it's more difficult
vector<double> sorted_nums(nums.size());
vector<string> sorted_str(str.size());
for ( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i ) {
    sorted_nums[i] = nums[idx[i]];
    sorted_str[i] = str[idx[i]];
}

std::cout << "Sort by numbers:\n";
for ( int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i ) {
    std::cout << sorted_nums[i] << ' ' << sorted_str[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Bob, these are really great solution, which work perfectly. I guess it should also work instead of <int< with <double>. How to get the sorted values (c++) in my_set out into a 1D array .. ? For instance int AY [i] = my_set.num [i] does not work. Many thanks for your ideas and help.

Comment: @joe well, in the last loop, instead of print the values, use them to fill any array you need. Later I'll update the answer.

Comment: Hi Bob,It looks like have to work hard to get on track with your ideas.The first C++ solution (set ..) worked well, but this last option (sort ..) looks almost perfect for me. Many thanks for your comprehensive views !

Answer (score -1):

You seem to intend to sort an array of integers (your compare function looks like that). But what you are actually handing over to qsort for sorting is a pointer to a structure that holds, among other stuff, an array.

So what you are actually trying to sort is one single struct ABCSort which is initialized and 9 other, uninitialized structures. This must fail.

Your qsort line should look like so:

```
qsort ((void*)&(abcsort.svsort), 10, sizeof (int), (compfn)compare);
```

Also, you should change the compare function so that it takes and works on  two pointers to integers:

```
int compare (int * e1, int * e2) {
   return *e1 - *e2;
}
```

EDIT:
After you have explained a bit better what you want, have a look at the following:

```
typedef int(compfn)(const void, const void*); 

#define MAXCARS 5

struct car { 
   int sortKey;
   double displacement; 
   char name[15];  /* Note I have decided this should be C */
}; 

/* This time we have an array of structs */
struct car cars [MAXCARS] = { 
   { 0, 1.9, "BMW" }, 
   { 0, 6.3, "Audi" }, 
   { 0, 0.5, "Fiat" },
   { 0, 25.0, "Humvee" },
   { 0, 0.05, "Minibike" }
};

int compare(struct car*, struct car*); 

void main(int argc, char *argv []) { 
   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < MAXCARS; i++)
       cars[i].sortKey = 100 - i;

   qsort((void *)&cars, MAXCARS, sizeof(struct car), (compfn)compare); 
} 

/* Note we are comparing struct car-s in here, based on their displacement */
int compare(struct car *elem1, struct car *elem2) { 
   return elem1->sortKey - elem2->sortKey;
}
```

Comment: This is not enough, since given your code this is going to fail: `int compare(struct ABCSort *elem1, struct ABCSort *elem2)` and `if (elem1->svSort< elem2->svSort)`. The answer is incomplete.

Comment: tofro: thanks but qsort ((void*)&(abcSort.svSort), 10, sizeof (int), (compfn)compare); is also not sorting both arrays. iksemyonov: if it's not complete what could I change ?

Comment: If you want to sort two arrays, you have to call qsort twice, once for each array. We have shown you how to do this for one of them and left the other one as exercise to you ;) Note you will be sorting C-strings for the other array. The comparison function and also the qsort call needs to be different for those.

Comment: @tofro sorry, but the second array contains `std::string` (this is partly an assumption because we don't see a `using std::string;` or a `using namespace std;` anywhere in the code), and the comparison operator is defined for `std::string`.

Comment: right again. But instead of assuming an std::string somewhere, we could just as well assume a typedef char [80] string ;) - Both is not there

Comment: Actually, I took this from a similar case which work. typedef int(*compfn)(const void*, const void*);
 typedef int(*compfn)(const void*, const void*);
 struct animal {
  int  number;
  char name[15];
 };

struct animal arrayAAA[3] = {
{ 1, "Ana" },
{ 5, "Elep" },
{ 8, "Hum" }}
int  compare(struct animal *, struct animal *);
void mainSort(void)
{
 qsort((void *)&arrayAAA, 5,sizeof(struct animal),(compfn)compare);
}
int compare(struct animal *elem1, struct animal *elem2)
{
 if (elem1->number < elem2->number)
  return -1;
 else if (elem1->number > elem2->number)
  return 1;
 else
}

Comment: @Joe That example sorts an array of structs (but only based on the number), not an array of integers. I think you should first tell us what exactly you want to sort....

Comment: tofro: the basic idea is to sort existing double array values and link the related strings. Simply like (4.5, "VW"), ((2.4, Skoda), (... Therefore, I craeted the struct ..

Comment: @joe, you created the struct on the wrong dimension, so to say. Think well, you will see that the value pairs should be structs themselves, since they're the objects you operate on.

Comment: iksemyonov: thanks for your feedback. Maybe, I was not clear enough. I have a 1D int array (svSort[10]) and a related string array (itemSort[10]) and combined them in the struct ABCSort. The idea is to only sort the struct (effectively the int and use the linked strings). This code perfectly works, when using struct ABCSort abcSort[3] = { { 1, "Ana" }, { 5, "Elep" }, { 8, "Hum" }}. Obviously there is something wrong filling the struct  data.

Comment: tofro: Thanks for the code example. Actually, that's exactly were I came from right at the beginning and which works well. My issue is still how to correctly feed the two arrays in the struct (what I tried with the for loop).

Comment: I don't get what you mean with "feed the two arrays in the struct". Initialising the values? Above you said ""the basic idea is to sort existing double array values and link the related strings" - I think that's what happens now....

Comment: In your example you used 5 data sets which works. In my code I used struct ABCSort abcSort;

int compare(struct ABCSort*, struct ABCSort*);

void mainSort()
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        abcSort.svSort[i] = 100 - i;
        abcSort.itemSort[i] = arrayREAD[i][2];
    }

Comment: Sorry, this was too fast .. Actually, I filled the struct abcSort with values from the arrays using the "for" loop (abcSort.svSort[i] = 100 - i; and abcSort.itemSort[i] = arrayREAD[i][2];. This new data could not be sorted.

Comment: tofro: Have you tried my code (similiar to yours except the for loop). It has no compiling or debugging issues but don't sort.

Comment: @Joe: Another modification. Should do what you want